# How can I make a transparent ComboBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I want to make a clear ComboBox. How do I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by clear? empty, invisible, greyed out?

Comment: I want to integrate it on the page comes from a graphic I want to be transparent and not disrupt the graphics
And help me make the color of the left frame Rafiq in combobox

Comment: How has this question got 2 upvotes, when it clearly does __not__ show research effort; is not useful; and is not clear?

Comment: How would you combine graphics in combobox? You could not reduce his frame. Maybe you know a way to lower the frame? Then I choose a color

Comment: Now it sounds like my article on code project is what you are after. See my post

Answer (score 1):

You will have to override Paint and draw the control yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I posted an article on CodeProject on how to take over the drawing of combo box to paint a flat border. It is not specifically about transparency drawing that you are after but hopefully offer a good starting point

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ComboBox_appears_flat.aspx

Comment: How is what you've done different from setting the [`FlatStyle` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.flatstyle.aspx) to "Flat"?

Comment: The article was written in 2005, back then there was no such setting as I said it in the article. It shows the internal of how you can take over the painting

Comment: Except that owner drawing is now well-supported by the framework, as well. The entire article could be replaced by simply mentioning the `WM_NC_PAINT` message. That's the only interesting detail that it provides.